# Not able to view or save the file using device file explorer.when i try to open or save i got error as shown in image

Tags: android-studio, local-storage

[see the image for error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmhdw.png)
Unable to access the file from my device using android's device explorer getting a error.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/ 
http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/
http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion

Comment: This question is not related to coding, but related to 'Android Studio' - accessing file from actual mobile device using device file explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!!!. Windows defender was the culprit I just turned off antivirus it's working fine now. But I won't recommend Turing off antivirus forever you can just add launcher of Android studio (studio64) in exclude list of your antivirus.